# AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist

Tags: android

Проблема возникает, когда пытаюсь запустить проект на другом компьютере

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="example.alexander.androidslideshow">

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ImageGridActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image_grid"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SlideShowActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_slide_show"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"></receiver>

    <activity android:name=".AlarmManagerActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Вот build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    packagingOptions{
        exclude'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.alexander.androidslideshow"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.marvinlabs:android-slideshow-widget:0.1.+@aar'
    compile 'net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.3.0'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
}
```

Comment: возможно на другом компьютере другая версия `gradle`

Comment: поможет ли в этом случае конвертация проекта при запуску?